# Get nested value from json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to retrieve data from google geocoding api. I can go response.results but if i try to define it more than that, like response.results.geometry then it's undefined? 
JSon response from google:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Detroit",
               "short_name" : "Detroit",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Wayne County",
               "short_name" : "Wayne County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Michigan",
               "short_name" : "MI",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Detroit, Michigan, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 42.45023,
                  "lng" : -82.91045099999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.255192,
                  "lng" : -83.287959
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 42.331427,
               "lng" : -83.0457538
           {........}
```

Comment: It's because `results` is an array, so you need to do something like `response.results[0].address_components[0].long_name` to get **Detroit**.

Comment: you need to loop throught the results

Comment: What is the value you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: @vlaz response was enough and I did not have to loop through it fortunately :p